# Use iPhone fingerprint sensor without Touch ID

Tags: ios, iphone, fingerprint, touch-id

Is it possible to read my own fingerprints without using Touch ID?

> iOS and other apps never access your fingerprint data, it's never
>   stored on Apple servers, and it's never backed up to iCloud or
>   anywhere else. Only Touch ID uses it, and it can't be used to match
>   against other fingerprint databases.

Because I can not get access to the iPhone fingerprint database, I would like to use the iPhone integrated fingerprint scanner and create my own fingerprint.

Comment: The documentation tells you that you can't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> iOS and other apps never access your fingerprint data

This statement clearly states you can't get any data from fingerprint sensor. All information is encrypted and stored on device which your application can never access being sandboxed.

Comment: Thought they just mean the fingerprint data that is stored on the iPhone and not the data that is generated by the scanner/sensor.